# Is there a way to rename the nth item in a list with CSS?

Tags: css

Example:

```
<ul id="section-tabs">
<li class="section"><a href="/accounts/1" title="Courses" class="courses">Courses</a></li>
<li class="section"><a href="/accounts/1/users" title="People" class="users">People</a></li>
<li class="section"><a href="/accounts/1/outcomes" title="Outcomes" class="outcomes">Outcomes</a></li>
```

Is it possible in anyway to rename "People" to "Users"?

(I do not have access to the HTML)